# How to make my table collapse by row in mobile view

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I'm trying to add a responsive table to an iframe in my website. The table looks good in desktop but not in mobile view. I have tried the @media to make the table collapse by row so that the first cell of each row will become vertically aligned in one column.

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
|    row head1      | data1 |              data2  |
|-------------------------------------------------| <--my table 
|    row head2      | data3 |              data4  |


|--------------------|
|    row head1       |    <- i want to have this in mobile view
|--------------------|
|    data1           |
|--------------------|
|    data2           |
|--------------------|
|    row head2       |
|--------------------|
|    data3           |
|--------------------|
|    data4           |
|--------------------|
```

Anything I did wrong in the following?

```css
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ffffff;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ffffff;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:0px 0px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ffffff;}
.tg .tg-iwtr{background-color:#34cdf9;color:#ffffff;vertical-align:top;}
.tg .tg-yzt1{background-color:#efefef;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-cxkv{background-color:#ffffff}
.tg .tg-bsv2{background-color:#efefef}
.tg .tg-3we0{background-color:#ffffff;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
  table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block ;

 
 
  }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg" style="width: 100%;" >
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 110px">
<col style="width: 108px">
<col style="width: 418px">
<col style="width: 578px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-iwtr" rowspan="2">04/08/2017</th>
    <td class="tg-bsv2">11:00 – 12:30</th>
    <td class="tg-bsv2">data</th>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-cxkv">15:00 – 17:00</td>
    <td class="tg-cxkv">data</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-iwtr">05/08/2017</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">11:00 – 12:30</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-iwtr" rowspan="2">06/08/2017</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">15:00 – 16:30</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">16:30 – 18:00</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-iwtr" rowspan="2">07/08/2017</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">15:00 – 16:30</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">16:30 – 18:00</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

The Css Looks fine to me. note that in the HTML you're opening a `<td>` but closing a `</th>`.

```css
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ffffff;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ffffff;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:0px 0px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ffffff;}
.tg .tg-iwtr{background-color:#34cdf9;color:#ffffff;vertical-align:top;}
.tg .tg-yzt1{background-color:#efefef;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-cxkv{background-color:#ffffff}
.tg .tg-bsv2{background-color:#efefef}
.tg .tg-3we0{background-color:#ffffff;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
@media all and (max-width: 479px) {
  table,
  thead,
  tbody,
  th,
  td,
  tr {
    display: block ;

 
 
  }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg" style="width: 100%;" >
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 110px">
<col style="width: 108px">
<col style="width: 418px">
<col style="width: 578px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-iwtr" rowspan="2">04/08/2017</th>
    <th class="tg-bsv2">11:00 – 12:30</th>
    <th class="tg-bsv2">data</th>
    <th class="tg-yzt1">data</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-cxkv">15:00 – 17:00</td>
    <td class="tg-cxkv">data</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-iwtr">05/08/2017</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">11:00 – 12:30</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-iwtr" rowspan="2">06/08/2017</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">15:00 – 16:30</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">16:30 – 18:00</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-iwtr" rowspan="2">07/08/2017</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">15:00 – 16:30</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
    <td class="tg-3we0">data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">16:30 – 18:00</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
    <td class="tg-yzt1">data</td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
```

Comment: But my problem has not been resolved as the table is not in one column when displayed in mobile view. The table is still not responsive, which looks exactly the same as desktop version. Any code that I missed there ?

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting output, the code-snippet iframes from stackoverflow sometimes don't play nice with with css media queries.
If you try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/az9g6zLe/), it should most definitely work when resizing the output frame